# creating a ConnectionString in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i want to create a connection to my database in my application on vb.net
i stored a procedure called "CTable" that will create tables if they don't exist

im using this code:

```
    Dim strConnection As String
    strConnection = "Data Source=Localhost; Initial Calalog=Northwind; Integrated Security=True"
    Dim MyConn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

    MyConn = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    Dim query As String = "EXEC CTable"

    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, MyConn)

    MyConn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MyConn.Close()
```

but he is giving this error: 
" An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'initial calalog'"

my question is : what should i put in my 'strConnection' variable to be able to execute my CTable Procedure????

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Connection string formats differ between different databases. What database are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Normal practice is to store your connection string in the `web.config` file.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the connection string. Try "Catalog" instead of "Calalog" ;)

Answer (score 0):

The word is `Catalog` not `Calalog`.

So this should work:

```
strConnection = "Data Source=Localhost; Initial Catalog=Northwind; Integrated Security=True"
```

Note that you also have to set the `CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

But always use the `Using` statement to ensure that unmanaged resources are disposed even on error:

```
Dim strConnection = "Data Source=Localhost; Initial Catalog=Northwind; Integrated Security=True"
Using MyConn = New sqlclient.SqlConnection()
    Using cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("EXEC CTable")
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        MyConn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using ' also closes the conection
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard Security

Data Source=serverName\instanceName;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Trusted Connection

Data Source=serverName\instanceName;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;

Comment: hey,
now am using this strConnection "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog= dbCourrier.mdf; Integrated Security=True;user id = Daniel; Password = ******; "

Comment: but i still have this error
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot open database "dbCourrier.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.