# After entering your login details, nothing happens

Tags: vb.net

When I enter the username and password, and click on login, nothing happens, as if there is no code. What is wrong with my code?

```
Dim Username As String = ""

con.Open()
Dim sql As String
Dim i As Boolean
sql = "SELECT [UserName], [Password] FROM tblLogin WHERE 

[UserName]=? AND [Password]=?;"

If txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter your credentials")

            Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If (i = True) Then
                MsgBox("Login successful")
                frmMain.Show()
            Else
                MsgBox("Login failed")
            End If
            cmd = Nothing
            con.Close()
```

Comment: none of those tags are synonyms of the others.  Please tag with the correct language only.

Comment: `Dim Username As String = ""` and other things in your code are only possible in VB.NET. It can neither be VBA, nor VB6.

Comment: If you'd bothered to use the debugger then you'd see exactly what the problem is. If you don't know how to debug then stop what you're doing and learn, then do it to that code.

Comment: See [working with commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/commands-and-parameters) on learn.microsoft.com, what is missing is the part that actually sends the parameters to the command; try adding `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(txtUsername.Text)` and `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(txtPassword.Text)` somewhere between `cmd = New OleDbCommand(...)` and `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Also note that the `OleDbConnection` object should have its `Dispose()` method invoked; you can ensure that by wrapping it in a `Using` block.

Comment: That said if clicking a button isn't doing anything (not even throwing an exception), verify that the button's `Click` event is being registered with the event handler procedure. The member signature should look something like `Private Sub LoginButton_Click() Handles LoginButton.Click`.

Comment: RE debugging: use F9 to place a *breakpoint* on a statement in your code; when F5-running the program, execution will stop at that statement (should then be highlighted in yellow as the *current statement*) and from there you can press F10 to step-through your code line by line, inspecting locals (see the "locals" toolwindow in VS, or just hover variable names with the mouse), and hit F5 to resume execution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing `End If` in this code snippet. I assume that it appears after the code you are showing us.

```vb
If txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please enter your credentials")

    Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    If (i = True) Then
        MsgBox("Login successful")
        frmMain.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Login failed")
    End If
    cmd = Nothing
    con.Close()
End If '<== this one is missing
```

This means that the query is only executed when username or password are empty according to `If txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then`.

The code should look like this:

```vb
If txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please enter your credentials")
Else
    Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    Dim rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    If rowsAffected  > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Login successful")
        frmMain.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Login failed")
    End If
    cmd = Nothing
    con.Close()
End If
```

Added an `Else`.

Aslo, `ExecuteNonQuery` returns an `Integer` telling you how many records have been affected. It does not return a Boolean.

And you seem to be creating and opening the connection before the if-statements decides whether the query will be executed. Creating and opening the connection should probably happen in the `Else` part as well. You should embed the connection in a [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement). See also this answer to [creating a ConnectionString in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17468865/880990)

---

As @jmcilhinney suggests in a comment, debug your code! Have a look at: [Tutorial: Learn to debug Visual Basic code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Comment: There is an End If and End Sub as well but still it only executes "Please enter your credentials" only.

Comment: Because either `txtUsername.Text` or `txtPassword.Text` is empty. Are you using the right textbox names? Set a breakpoint on the `If` and you will see what they contain.